# How to use dialog from another java file?

Tags: java

I have code in "java1.java" file.

```
package javaapplication9;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class DialogExample{

    DialogExample(){
        JFrame f= new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JButton b = new JButton ("Click");
        b.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                //Dialog code
                JDialog d = new JDialog(f, "Dialog",Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                d.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
                d.setSize(100, 100);
                d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JButton b1 = new JButton ("Click");
                b1.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(d, "Note");
                    }
                });
                d.add(b1);
                d.setVisible(true);
                //End dialog
            }
        });
        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new DialogExample();
    }
}
```

I want to code dialog d in "java2.java" file. Because I want to use multiple dialogs. If to all in 1 file will be very difficult to handle. How to do that?
I newbie java. Thanks for read.

Comment: Did you try to actually do it? If you tried then you'd notice that you can use class declared in another file (assuming it's in the same package or that you are importing it if it's in different package). BTW: You cannot have your files named java1.java etc. They have to be matching the name of the only public class that you declare within.

Comment: @MirekPluta I see. But file name java1.java for illustration only. Thanks for your suggestion. I don't understand how to use another class in the package. Along with elf01b reply below. I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* 06. Java Dialog in two classes */

```
package Example;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Dialog02 {
    JDialog dialog02;
    Dialog02() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3, 1 ) );
        dialog02 = new JDialog( f, "Dialog",
                Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL );
        dialog02.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3, 1 ) );
        dialog02.setSize( 200, 200 );
        dialog02.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        JButton b1 = new JButton( "Click" );
        b1.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( dialog02, "Note" );
            }
        } );
        f.add( b1 );
        f.setSize( 500, 500 );
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible( true );
    }
}

class DialogExample {
    DialogExample() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3, 1 ) );
        f.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        JButton b = new JButton( "Click" );
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                Dialog02 d02 = new Dialog02();
            }
        } );
        f.add( b );
        f.setSize( 400, 300 );
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible( true );
    }
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        new DialogExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's better than my code. But still in 1 file. Is there a way to split 2 java files?

Comment: You just need to put class Dialog02 into other file java1.java and then import java1.java into class DialogExample. I like copy-paste code one-time in one file for easy learning.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your suggestion. Along with Mirek Pluta reply above. I can try.